# URLSessionDownloadTask call is not always working when used to download multiple concurrently

Tags: ios, swift

I used this code for downloading multiple assets concurrently, but
once in a while the code fail.

I added retry  for this call, but this does not feel like  a good solution.
any idea why the call for downloadTask fails?

Is there some kind of limitations, like number of concurrent task?
or should I use specific queue?

```
@objc class Downloader : NSObject {

  @objc var  fileUrl:URL
  @objc var  destinationUrl:URL
  @objc var  dispachGroup:DispatchGroup?
  @objc var  optionalAsset:Bool
  @objc var  retryCalled:Int
  var downloadTask:URLSessionDownloadTask? = nil

  @objc init(dispachGroup:DispatchGroup,fileURL: URL , destinationFileUrl: URL, optionalAsset:Bool) {
    self.dispachGroup = dispachGroup
    self.fileUrl = fileURL
    self.destinationUrl = destinationFileUrl
    self.optionalAsset = optionalAsset
    self.retryCalled = 0

  }

  @objc func stop() {
    downloadTask?.cancel()
  }

  @objc func preformDownload(delegate:URLSessionDownloadDelegate, delay:TimeInterval, timeout:TimeInterval) {

    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
    let urlSession =  URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
    var request = URLRequest(url: self.fileUrl)
    request.timeoutInterval = timeout
    self.downloadTask?.cancel()
    self.downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: request)
    self.downloadTask?.resume()
  }
}
```